# Does a laser toner cartridge have to be empty before refilling?

Tags: printer, toner

I would like to know if a laser toner cartridge have to be empty before I refill it. Since I ordered a toner bottle online and the description said it had to be empty.

I emptied the toner and then realised that there was huge amount of powder which came out.

I was thinking there was lot left and so why did I have to empty it?

I want to know that if laser toner cartridge is "empty" then if the then powder inside disappears while printing or if it's just a residue.

Comment: Please specify the brand of your original toner and the one you bought online

Comment: Original was TN 3145, i bought http://cgi.ebay.com.au/Brother-TN-3060-TN3060-TN-3030-TN3030-toner-refill-kit_W0QQitemZ310193392668QQcmdZViewItemQQptZAU_Computers_Printer_Accessories?hash=item4838f78c1c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are refilling with cheap toner into a genuine one, you are probably best off emptying as it will be different and you may have a lot of imperfections when they mix.

If you are topping up one that has already been refilled, I would say the answer is no because it is the same stuff.

Just be careful if you do this to much as they may change the consistency or formulae between batches/bottles.

Lastly, make sure it really is the toner you are emptying and not the waste toner or similar as this would have to be emptied each time.

(Out of curiosity, what printer/cartridge is this?)

Comment: I think i emptied the waste toner and put the toner in that. what should i do now

Comment: Why -1?... Anyway, no - you do not want to put anything in the waste toner, waste toner is for old/bad/used/discarded toner. You want to empty it but put the new toner in the main compartment.

Comment: i have checked that was the main component . My rpinter is Brother HL 5240 .Its similar to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0sVP7szG5g

I think i did not used precaution and some particles have gone inside my body . Is that ok or its very bad

Second i ahve put toner by guess so i don't know whether it was 100g or not may less

Comment: It can be bad, it really depends on the quantity, best case scenario - lands somewhere safe and does no damage or you get a few dirty prints until it goes away... worst case scenario, it gets in something critical and brakes the printer... be careful and try to clean it.

Comment: i will try to print now and will see what happens. THANKS FOR HELP